# How can I create a database with a user name and password in mongodb in mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, passwords, admin

I'm trying to create a database with user name and password, some answers says to addUser for admin .but there isn't any database called in by mongodb.

I run the mongodb with super user privilege.

```
MacBook:~ root# mongod
```

or

```
 MacBook:~ macbook$ mongo
```

the in new tab I run following command

```
MacBook:~ root# mongo
```

then I see for my dbs with `show dbs` command it show followings

```
>show dbs
clist  0.078GB
hinfo  0.078GB
local  0.078GB
```

I tried with this `local` database with `system.indexes` but I didn't get any succesful result. am I wrong with doing this. hope your help. I'm new to mongodb and I'm using `monogo 3.2.4 versioin`

Answer (score 13):

Since it's the first Stack Overflow link from *"mongodb create db with username and password"* query in Google, here's the answer:

```
use mydb
db.createUser(
   {
     user: "myuser",
     pwd: "mypassword",
     roles: [ "dbOwner" ]
   }
)
```

These commands will create a database named `mydb`, assign a user named `myuser` with password `mypassword` and grant him full access rights on that db.

Make sure you are admin beforehand, so that you're able to create dbs and users.

[Note] In order to get the newly created database to show in the list returned by command `show dbs`, you need to insert at least one document into a collection of the newly created database. For example:

```
> mydoc = { firstName : "Adam" }
> db.mycollection.insert( mydoc  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Authentication in MongoDB is done at the instance level. What that means is that when you start mongod you will need to pass the `--auth` option.

When authentication is enabled you will need to create users to give them access to the appropriate database(s). The admin database won't exist by default, it will be created dynamically when you create the first user.

See the [Enable Authentication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) page for details and examples.

Comment: isn't it possible now

Comment: Sorry, revised my answer for clarity.

Comment: I created a user as  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/ this tutorial. It successfully created an admin user. but with or without login with username and password, I can access any database.is this apply for new databases